# Unable to retrieve data area value using QXXRTVDA and brace-initialized values

Tags: c, ibm-midrange

I was trying to do simple data area value retrieval using C source from here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/qxxrtvd.htm

And... the code failed to do certain retrieval.

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct _DTAA_NAME_T {
   char dtaa_name[10]; /* name of data area */
   char dtaa_lib[10];  /* library that contains data area */
}_DTAA_NAME_T;
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xxdtaa.h>

#define DATA_AREA_LENGTH  30
#define START             6
#define LENGTH            7

int main(void)
{
  char uda_area[DATA_AREA_LENGTH];

 /* Retrieve data from user-defined data area currently in MYLIB */
  _DTAA_NAME_T dtaname = {"USRDDA    ", "MYLIB     "};

 /* Use the function to retrieve some data into uda_area.        */
  QXXRTVDA(dtaname,START,LENGTH,uda_area);

 /* Print the contents of the retrieved subset.                  */
  printf("uda_area contains %7.7s\n",uda_area);

}
```

There are several problems in this brace-intialized values:

```
_DTAA_NAME_T dtaname = {"USRDDA    ", "MYLIB     "};
```

1. Values can not get initialized with 10 characters value - only 9 chars + null byte. 
   Initializing values with 10 characters will lead to compilation error.
2. Initializing it with anything less than 10 characters will lead to null byte appending thus the `QXXRTVDA` will not find any values as soon as there's no such library with null byte ending.

Comment: Not real sure what your issue was, this worked for me without modification (other than changing the data area and library name, not the length of the constants). Apparently Point #1 is incorrect.

Comment: I am using v7.1

Comment: @jmarkmurphy re Point #1: maybe I've interpreted message `CZP0280(30) The initializer is too long.` for line `_DTAA_NAME_T dtaara = {"ABCDEFGHIJ", "KLMNOPQRST"};` incorrectly? I'm on v7.2 TR8

Comment: I don't get that error. Is this the whole program?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I've found is to avoid brace-initialization and initialize values with direct bytes copying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xxdtaa.h>
#include <QSYSINC/MIH/CPYBLA>

#define DATA_AREA_LENGTH  30
#define START             6
#define LENGTH            7

int main(void)
{
  char uda_area[DATA_AREA_LENGTH];
  _DTAA_NAME_T dtaara;

  memset( &dtaara, ' ', sizeof(dtaara));
  cpybla( dtaara.dtaa_name, "USRDDA", 6);
  cpybla( dtaara.dtaa_lib, "MYLIB", 5);

  /* Use the function to retrieve some data into uda_area.        */
  QXXRTVDA(dtaname,START,LENGTH,uda_area);

  /* Print the contents of the retrieved subset.                  */
  printf("uda_area contains %7.7s\n",uda_area);
}
```

Hope this helps somebody not to waste time on such a basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

The null-termation byte is only used to initialize the array if there is room for it.

```
#include <xxdtaa.h>

main()
{
   _DTAA_NAME_T dtaara = {"ABCDEFGHIJ", "KLMNOPQRST"};
   return;
}
```

In debug:

```
EVAL dtaara:x 20                                                       
   00000     C1C2C3C4 C5C6C7C8 C9D1D2D3 D4D5D6D7   - ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP  
   00010     D8D9E2E3 ........ ........ ........   - QRST............
```

Comment: Btw keep getting `CZP0280(30) The initializer is too long.` for line `_DTAA_NAME_T dtaara = {"ABCDEFGHIJ", "KLMNOPQRST"};`
What I'm doing wrong? I'm on v7.2 TR8

Comment: The C++ compiler issues that message. If you need to use C++ instead of C for this, then you'll have to use something like memcpy to set the values.